# Extract all SVG between two unicode values fontforge

Tags: python, svg, unicode, fonts, fontforge

So I have a font that i made a while back din't do very much of anything with it at the time, i lost a few of the original SVGs when i have reinstalled the OS on my computer, The font is full unicode with lots of characters, all the icons saved in the font are outside the normal character range, i know it is possible to extract a bunch of SVG from the font using this command

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' Typeface.ttf
```

and

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectAll(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' Typeface.ttf
```

However the first misses the icons completely, and the second is no different. all the icons are between two points in the file starting at `U+e000` and going through to `U+e17d` i want to know how i can extract all the icons between these two points. and if possible match with a namelist.txt for naming.

Answer (score 1):

**How to extract several characters between two Unicode values from fontforge?**

The conceptually cleanest way would be to iterate over the hexadecimal number-range you specified and call font[char_name].export() on every single one of them. However, this comes with the hassle of incrementing hexadecimal numbers (which while feasible is a bit more involved than what I'm going to propose).

The following for-loop paired with the function 'nameFromUnicode(position)' should do the trick while staying (mostly) clear of hexadecimals. The function 'nameFromUnicode(position)' takes the position of a Unicode character as an integer and returns the name of the character at that position (something like Uni2D42). This name can then be passed to font[that_char_name].export() to export it. To find the starting and ending position of your range in decimal simply interpret the character names as a hexadecimal number and convert it to decimal. In your case e000 becomes 57344 and e17d becomes 57725. The range in decimal would then be from 57344 to 57725.

The following code snippet is a bare bone loop extracting the characters in the specified range (although for '.png' instead of '.svg'; adapting it should be fairly straight forward though).

```
from fontforge import *
font = open("/path/to/your/.ttf/file")
for position in range(57344,57726):
    glyph = nameFromUnicode(position)
    font[glyph].export(font[glyph].glyphname + ".png", 150)
```

I don't quite understand your second question about matching against a namelist.txt. If after 5 years you still crave an answer your welcome to elaborate and I'll see if I can come up with an answer.